# Re-setting headers/ content type in Rest-Assured

Tags: automation, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am new to rest-Assured and I am doing upload file and then do a get request to see a content. For the upload the content-type is multipart/form-data and I am using following code to set the values

```
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().accept("application/json"));
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().contentType("multipart/form-data"));
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().header("authorization", ConfigHelper.getString(user)));
```

For retrieve content, I am again re-setting the values to the below code.

```
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().contentType("application/json"));
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().header("authorization", ConfigHelper.getString(user)));
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().accept("application/json"));
```

But when I try to execute the upload, I am getting the error as
"

> request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data

"

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong here, Initially when it was only upload it worked fine but the moment I added to GET content, I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [rest-assured] is with chaining api. In the code above each time it creates a new request specification instead of updating an existing one.

Use code as follows

```
RequestSpecification request = given()
            .accept("application/json")
            .contentType("multipart/form-data")
            .header("authorization", ConfigHelper.getString(user));
```

Comment: If I do that , if I need to have multipart for one request and If I dont have multipart for the second request, it doesnot clear it for the second request, For eg: 1st request is for upload and second is for get content. I set multipart for upload but i dont need that for get content. How do I clear that?